# Finding irreducible polynomial

Tags: ring-theory

[image]

- 1, 3 False: $f_{2^2}(x)=f_4(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+1)(x+1)$ is not irreducible.
- 2 True: Cyclotomic polynomial of order prime.

I am not sure about 4.

Here's my guess about 4: $x^{p^{e-1}}$ is itself a variable and hence by Eisenstein's crieterion $f_P(x^{p^{e-1}})$ is irreducible.

Please tell me the exact logic and answer for 4.

Comment: I do not immediately see how do you differentiate between options two and three? could you please explain..

Comment: Take $p=2,e=2.$

Comment: My question is why do you think eisenstein work/doesn't work when you have same kind of polynomial in both cases twp and three...

Comment: eisenstein works only for prime $p.$ For nonprime nothing can be said.

Comment: yes but that prime is not occurring as a coefficient right?.. Do you now see the problem?

Comment: Please somebody help us omitting the missing link between us !!!!!!

Comment: My point is : $$f_p(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dots+x^2+x+1$$ and $$f_{p^e}=x^{p^e-1}+x^{p^e-2}+\dots+x^2+x+1$$ you do not have much difference if you want to use Eisenstein for this polynomials... So, I guess you have to say something more?

Comment: Please tell me what should I tell more.

Comment: Just tell me one thing.. How do you use Eisenstein for $1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{p-1}$?

Comment: Oopssssssssssssssss......its $p^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial and hence ... gooooooodddddddddddddd!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: That is what I was asking you for...